# plotting with subsets of data

Tags: python, plot, subset

So i have various arrays of data where treatments are coded with dummy variables like

```
x=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
z=[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
d=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,0,1,1,10,20,35,50,1,10,15,20,25]
```

and I would like to plot four plots at the same time in separate figures with each of the combination of treatments as one plot.

so

```
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(d,y[x==0],[z==0])

plt.figure(2) 
plt.subplot(412)
plt.plot(d,y[x==1],[z==0])

plt.figure(3)
plt.subplot(421)
plt.plot(d,y[x==0],[z==1])

plt.figure(4)
plt.subplot(422)
plt.plot(d,y[x==1],[z==1])

p.show()
```

but I get an error saying the third argument has to be a format string.

I don't want to break up the data into smaller chunks before plotting as I will be running the data through a regression model prior to plotting and it seems as though it may complicate things a little too much for me.

Any help would be appreciated as I am very inexperienced with python.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification from OP:
I'm trying to get 4 graphs in one pane with;

1. the first plot being a ~ y when x=0 and z=0,
2. the 2nd plot being a ~ y when x=1 and z= 0
3. the third being a ~ y when x=0 and z=1 and
4. the last being a ~ y when x=1 and z=1

To achieve this you will need to extract the correct data before plotting it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
z=[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
y=[1,2,3,4,5,0,0,1,0,1,1,10,20,35,50,1,10,15,20,25]
d=[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]


plt.figure(1)

zipped = list(zip(x, z, y, d))
filtered = [(ey, ed) for ex, ez, ey, ed in zipped if ex==0 and ez==0]
unzipped = list(zip(*filtered))
plotx = unzipped[1]
ploty = unzipped[0]

plt.subplot(411)
plt.title("x=0 z=0")
plt.plot(plotx, ploty, 'o-')

zipped = list(zip(x, z, y, d))
filtered = [(ey, ed) for ex, ez, ey, ed in zipped if ex==0 and ez==1]
unzipped = list(zip(*filtered))
plotx = unzipped[1]
ploty = unzipped[0]

plt.subplot(412)
plt.title("x=1 z=0")
plt.plot(plotx, ploty, 'o-')

zipped = list(zip(x, z, y, d))
filtered = [(ey, ed) for ex, ez, ey, ed in zipped if ex==1 and ez==0]
unzipped = list(zip(*filtered))
plotx = unzipped[1]
ploty = unzipped[0]

plt.subplot(413)
plt.title("x=0 z=1")
plt.plot(plotx, ploty, 'o-')

zipped = list(zip(x, z, y, d))
filtered = [(ey, ed) for ex, ez, ey, ed in zipped if ex==1 and ez==1]
unzipped = list(zip(*filtered))
plotx = unzipped[1]
ploty = unzipped[0]

plt.subplot(414)
plt.title("x=1 z=1")
plt.plot(plotx, ploty, 'o-')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm trying to get 4 graphs in one pane with;

the first plot being a ~ y when x=0 and z=0, 
the 2nd plot being a ~ y when x=1 and z= 0 
the third being a ~ y when x=0 and z=1 
and the last being a ~ y when x=1 and z=1.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your clarification.